# Evitar copias temporales en llamada a lambdas

Tags: c++, c++11, paso-por-referencia, paso-por-valor

Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
class Utf8Writer {
  struct ZoneData {
    uint32_t begin; // codepoint inicial.
    uint32_t end; // codepoint final.
  };

  const ZoneData *findCodepoint( uint32_t cp, FontId fid );
};

const ZoneData *Utf8Writer::findCodepoint( uint32_t cp, FontId fid ) {
  auto iter = std::find_if( fid->cbegin( ), fid->cend( ), [cp] ( ZoneData i ) { return ( cp >= i.begin ) && ( cp <= i.end ); } );

  return ( iter == fid->cend( ) ) ? nullptr : &( *iter );
}
```

Funciona perfectamente, salvo que **es un error**. Lo que yo realmente quería hacer es:

```
const ZoneData *Utf8Writer::findCodepoint( uint32_t cp, FontId fid ) {
  auto iter = std::find_if( fid->cbegin( ), fid->cend( ), [cp] ( const ZoneData &i ) { return ( cp >= i.begin ) && ( cp <= i.end ); } );

  return ( iter == fid->cend( ) ) ? nullptr : &( *iter );
}
```

De hecho, si miramos la doc de `std::find_if( )`:

```
template< class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate > InputIt find_if( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p );
```

siendo `UnaryPredicate` -> `bool pred( const Type &a );`

Entiendo que, en la primera versión, el compilador **crea un temporal, llamando al constructor-copia por defecto**. Resulta que la clase `ZoneData` es mas compleja de lo mostrado: incluye `std::vector` y otras *cosillas*, y su copia no es trivial (ni en tiempo ni en uso de memoria).

- ¿ Es posible evitar la creación de temporales en las llamadas a *lambda*, para futuras ocasiones, sin *tocar* la clase `ZoneData` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puede ser buena idea usar un `static_assert` que falle si el parámetro de la lambda no es una referencia, para conseguirlo necesitamos usar la cabecera [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) y su utilidad [`std::is_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_reference):

Este código fallará:

```
const ZoneData *Utf8Writer::findCodepoint( uint32_t cp, FontId fid ) {
  auto iter = std::find_if( fid->cbegin( ), fid->cend( ), [cp] ( ZoneData i )
//          'i' es una instancia, podría ser copia o movido ---> ~~~~~~~~~~
{
    // La aserción falla pues 'i' no es una referencia
    static_assert(std::is_reference_v<decltype(i)>, "Evita copiar el parametro!");
    return ( cp >= i.begin ) && ( cp <= i.end );
} );
```

Mientras que este debería funcionar sin problemas:

```
const ZoneData *Utf8Writer::findCodepoint( uint32_t cp, FontId fid ) {
  auto iter = std::find_if( fid->cbegin( ), fid->cend( ), [cp] ( const ZoneData &i )
//                     'i' es una referencia, no será copia ---> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
{
    // La aserción NO falla pues 'i' no es una referencia
    static_assert(std::is_reference_v<decltype(i)>, "Evita copiar el parametro!");
    return ( cp >= i.begin ) && ( cp <= i.end );
} );
```

Comment: ¡¡ Perfecto !! :-O

Comment: Sin embargo, me parece mucho más costoso escribir un `static_assert` con su condición y mensaje de error que escribir un `&` antes del parámetro de la lambda ¿o pretendes hacer una macro para envolver todo?

Comment: Ni una ni otra, de momento. Simple curiosidad. No se me ocurría el como hacerlo :-)

Comment: @Trauma también puede ser buena idea deshabilitar el constructor copia de la clase. Si las copias son tan pesadas como comentas puede tener más sentido disponer de una función específica para esa tarea que dificulte la creación de copias implícitas

Comment: @eferion Si, también. Ya lo tuve en cuenta, y en este caso concreto, como indicas, sería lo mas práctico. La pregunta era, mayormente, por curiosidad :-)